# Clicking Javascript links using selenium webdriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I've been working on automations for a few months now, and for a recent project, I came across a Javascript link with href format as "javascript:srcUp" and no "htm" at the end. I've tried multiple ways of identifying this element, including css_selector, xpath, link_text, execute_script, etc. But none of the methods seem to work. With the link_text method, I was able to identify the element, but the click command didn't really do anything. Was wondering if anyone here has faced this issue, and if someone has, it would be great if you could share a possible solution.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Looks like the basis of a good question. Improving the title so that it is a question and is specific will help readers, that may have the answer, to search for your question. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help on asking a good question.

Comment: You say "the click command didn't really do anything". What if you click the link when you're *not* running in Selenium, does it "do anything" then? If you get the same results inside or outside of Selenium, then I'd say it's not a Selenium problem.

Comment: Hey Conrad, clicking on the link outside selenium takes me to a different page, so I think it is a Selenium problem. Let me know if you know anything about solving this. Thanks